# Typescript inheritance - set variable of type parent to a child class

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

I have an inheritance structure like this...

```
class A {
  data1: string
}

class B extends A {
  data2: string

  constructor(){
  super()
  }
}

class C extends A {
  data3: string

  constructor(){
  super()
  }
}
```

and I want to set a variable of type A to one of the subclasses like this

```
class someClass {
someProp: A
}

let variable = new someClass()
variable.someProp = new B()
```

Yet, when I go to use the props on variable.someProp expecting to be able to use data2, I can only access data1

Any help is appreciated, thx!

Comment: This is by design in typescript. You should just leave out the `: A`.

Comment: "*Yet, when I go to use the props expecting to be able to use data2, I can only access data1*" because `A` does not have a `data2`. Why would TS allow it? You might have even assigned a `C` to the variable which *also* doesn't have a `data2`. It seems like you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to solve here? What is the core problem?

Comment: @VLAZ I want to create a class that has a composition of type A which can accept and use any of class A's child classes

Comment: @trinalbadger587 I could do that, but that kindof defeats the purpose of ts and then there is no intellisense

Comment: Right but why would an `A` have `data2`? It doesn't. And `C` doesn't. So if you try to use `data2`, then your class *doesn't* work with `A` nor just any child of `A`. It only works with `B`.

Comment: @VLAZ so does ts just not acknowledge child classes as valid types to use instead of the parent type? I thought that was possible in other languages. Plus ts isn't throwing any errors when I assign B to A.

Comment: This wouldn't even work in other languages. You *can* use a `B` where `A` is expected - same in Java or C#, for example. However, in all cases you'd only be able to use what `A` has *because you've declared it as `A`*. In Java you can assign a `LinkedList` (a `B`) where a `List` (an `A`) is expected. But you cannot use anything that is specific to `LinkedList`.

Comment: @VLAZ Ok, that makes sense but also doesn't make sense at the same time. If you couldn't use any of the stuff on LinkedList why even set it to that type in the firstplace lol?

Comment: You can definitely assign a `B` or a `C` to a property annotated as `A`, but you can't just take a property annotated as `A` and treat it like a `B` or a `C`.  TypeScript does not automatically narrow from `A` to `B` upon assignment (unless `A` is a union type and `B` is some subset of the members of `A`).  If you want to use generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjJa8w) you can keep track of the subtype of `A` passed into `SomeClass`, but this still doesn't allow arbitrary assignments and type mutations.

Comment: @IDrumsey Because a `LinkedList` has specific *behaviour*. Some part of the code may want a `List` as it only cares about ordered data. But you can define which sub-type you want which can influence how the program works *without* changing the type of List that should be passed in. Allows for a more dynamic way of handling things. If you *really do* need `LinkedList` specifically and other implementations are not useful, then you can declare the type accepted as `LinkedList`. It's what you seem to be trying to do here - if you need `data2`, then only `B` satisfies that.

Comment: @VLAZ Ok, I think I get it. I just need to explicitly use B. Thx!